# 800MB free RAM yet home screen redraws?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, ram, nova-launcher

my lowest priority app-kill min-free level engages at 64MB.

if I have 800MB of free RAM as reported in OSMonitor, why is the garbage collecting Nova Launcher assets? I can't even.

BTW, I have noticed this behavior in Android for many years, across launchers, across phones. I don't think it ever really got fixed-- remedied perhaps; I think people just gave up fussing. From the user's perspective, nothing should be cleared from RAM unless RAM is needed.

Comment: It might also be possible that Nova Launcher itself invalidates the view every so often so a redraw is invoked.

Comment: @ChromoZoneX this seems to be dependent on my use of ZRAM frontswap and Kernel Same-Page Merge in the custom kernel I run, two kernel-level features that 'add' about 500MB more RAM to my device by 'more efficiently' using it-- in other words, this behavior appears to be RAM dependent. Does that change anything? Further thought on this matter inspired me to write this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/113245/how-can-i-control-when-onpause-runs-on-android-apps

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather old question but Nova Launcher has an option to stop (most) redraws.

It can be found in Nova Settings > Advanced (at the bottom of the list).

It reads:

> #### Aggressive desktop
>
> Persistence, caching, and preloading to reduce redraws. Comparable to Keep in Memory option of Android 2.x launchers.

It's not a good idea for phones with low RAM (<=1GB), but if you have 800MB free (so, assumingly, your phone has 1.5 or 2GB), it should be just fine.

There should also be `(persistent)` next to the app name in Android Settings > Developer options > Process stats after changing that option.